# Webpack / PostCSS - Unable to use classes from the inline styles generated by Webpack

Tags: webpack, cherrypy, postcss

I am trying to setup Webpack(PostCSS) within a CherryPy application.  Webpack appears to be generating inline styles correctly, the following is my my loader within webpack.config.js

`{
    test:   /\.css$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1!postcss-loader"
 }`

When I run 'webpack', it appears to correctly generate the 'test-class' styles from my stylesheets/main.css file inline within the main generated output.js file....

`exports.push([module.id, ".W_8vO1mwnWhjGJpClgHqm {\n  /* color: $matt; */\n  color: green;\n  background: red;\n}\n", ""]);`

The generated output.js file is then included in a script tag within my main.html page.  However, when I try to use the 'test-class' that is generated above, applying it has no effect on the element.  In the webpack documentation, it mentions the following

`// in your modules just require the stylesheet
// This has the side effect that a <style>-tag is added to the DOM.
require("./stylesheet.css");`

I am unclear which module this is referring to.  Any insight would be much appreciated.

edit: updating with full webpack.config.js

```

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
//post css
var precss       = require('precss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');


module.exports = {

  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry: "./test.js",
  output: {
    filename: 'almostTest.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static')
},
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
      {
        test:   /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1!postcss-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  postcss: [
              precss,
              autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions']  })
            ]
}
```

```

Answer (score 1):

To use the CSS in your application bundled by Webpack, you must `import` or `require` that file into your entry file.

A practice that I take is to create an `index.css` file which is located on the same place as your `index.js` entry file, and then to require it from your `index.js` file.

Then, inside `index.css`, you require all of your other apps CSS files.

[Here is an example of a Webpack starter I've written importing the .scss file](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular-starter-es6-webpack/blob/master/app/index.js) and [the main .scss file which imports all of my other components style sheets via native imports which scss-loader treats like requires.](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular-starter-es6-webpack/blob/master/app/index.scss)

Otherwise, unless the styles are imported into your entry file in some way, the styles will not be accessible to your app.

## EDIT:

I notice that you have `modules=` defined in your loader query for `css-loader` this will default your css to be defined as [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). [See here in the css-loader docs for more details](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#css-modules)

Short answer: Remove the querystring from your loader definition so it looks like:
`css-loader?importLoaders=1` and you should be able to see your styles and access it from anywhere in your app.

Comment: Thanks Sean.  I am currently requiring in my test.js(using as my entry file)
```require('./index.css');
```
Still no luck though.
I have added my full webpack.config.js above.

Comment: Updated answer for you. I believe it is because you have local css scoping turned on with the `modules` definition in the query string.

Comment: Sean you are spot on, thank you so much!  I have removed CSS modules for the moment and will deal with those another day!